# clang on OSX: -finstrument-functions link errors

Tags: macos, clang, instrumentation

I'm trying to use `__cyg_profile_func_*` with `-finstrument-functions` to do specific checks before and after functions run (eg, to check for Mach port leaks and such). This is on OS X.

The code is written and functional, but I have a ton of undefined references to, for example,

```
std::__1::basic_ios<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::init(std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >*)
```

It seems like perhaps some sort of inlining is taking place, but the instrumentation is still trying to reference a non-inlined version of the function. Is it possible to exempt the standard C++ library from instrumentation? Or, possible to completely disable inlining in clang for this particular circumstance?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm having the exactly same problem. It seems like enabling -finstrument-functions makes clang unable to link against libc++ :/

Answer (score 0):

In gcc,`-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list=stdlib/include` would do what you want. However, it is not implemented in clang yet (at least trunk doesn't recognize this option).

Answer (score 0):

Clang has an option `-finstrument-functions-after-inlining` which will work in this case. yes it is unfortunate clang does not support disabling instrumentation on a file/directory basis. If instrumentation is too much trouble then changing the source code of standard C++ library to add attributes may help as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69474100/811335